# How to use Lightsail for Hosting & CDN with Route53

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, cdn, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

So, We have a wordpress website deployed through LightSail service of AWS. The DNS management is being done through route53. Now, we want to deploy CDN through lightsail but when we deploy the certificates are not getting validated.

Lightsail is prompting to shift DNS management from Rout53 to Lightsail...which is not possible as this would require change in nameservers that is not possible now.

Is there any way, we can deploy CDN on lightsail but DNS management through rout53 ?

The distribution is getting deployed but not working because of certificate error.